# How to determine why even the Administrator account is locked down?

Tags: windows-7, administrator

I inherited a network of computers, and some of them are being used by people who need complete lock down. The previous techs before me did something that caused the Local Administrator account to basically have no privileges. I was able to create a new Administrator user (for testing, just called **asdf**), but they are still locked down from things such as changing Local Printers (adding, changing, removing), changing hardware drivers, or even installing software.

I have checked through `gpedit.msc` and `secpol.msc` to try to look for settings that have changed, but none of them seem to affect this behaviour. I can run the below Powershell script and it returns True (meaning I'm running as the Administrator): `([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal] [Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal‌​.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")`

I am at a loss. It's on a domain, but running from Samba 3, so no policies are being downloaded to it. It is also not on the network right now, as I try logging in with the local Admin accounts. What can I try next?

Comment: did you look at all the GPOs that applied to the computers?

Comment: Yup. Didn't see anything that stood out

Comment: is it just the local admin account?  or anyone with local admin privs?

Comment: Anyone at all. That's why I'm confused

Comment: well if its *anyone* with local admin privs, that definitely points to GP or local security policy.  I would check any enabled local system policies against a machine that is working normally.  Perhaps they removed the administrator group from certain policies.

Comment: @Keltari Answered below. Thanks for the help though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the GPEdit snap in, but couldn't find anything weird. But someone reminded me about the [RSOP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758010%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), or Resultant Set of Policies. While reading the Microsoft documentation, I came across the page for the tools, and found the command `gpresult`. Checking the help, I saw that if you add the `/r` switch, it gives a report of the policies in effect. I ran that command, and found out that the Administrators were added to the Guests group!

I confirmed this by going into Computer Management (right-click on **My Computer** and choose **Manage**), then *Local Users*, and choosing *Groups*. Once in there, I opened the *Guests* group, and looked at its members - It had **Guest** (user) and **Authenticated Users** (group)! I removed the Authenticated Users group, logged off and back on, and I was able to make the maintenance changes I needed for this system.

Comment: Interesting method...  I wonder how secure that actually is...

Comment: Well, they can't open the settings to enable Internet access, they are blocked from installing software or drivers, or changing policies (their normal accounts from the server go into Guest anyways, the users aren't logging in as Admins)